# Django Ajax success send context in new url

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I have a first page with a Launch button, the process is done and them all is redirect to a result page where I can download the different results. Without Ajax and with "regular" Django, the process is working. However, because of other functionalities in the first page, I have to work with Ajax. And if I do not redefined the success part of Ajax, nothing is happening..

I have a function view for the first page :

```
def launchCtd(request):
"""
This Function is activate when user click on the launch button of the convertToDose page.
It receive the request, create the JSON file and launch the ConvertToDose Analysis. Then it redirect to the Result page
"""

if request.method == 'POST':

    #DO stuff
    context = {
        'filename': img_out_path,
        'protocol_file': json_pactrlRectth,
    }

    #return render(request, 'result.html', context)
    return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)# I trie to pass the url but it was not a success...

else:
    #Ini Forms
    context = {
        #Send Forms
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

the template of the first page (only ajax part)

```
$.ajax({
url: "",
type: "POST",
data: formData,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
},
success: function(data){
    //print okay with JSONResponse in view
    console.log(data.protocol_file)
    
    //First try to send data in new url => undefined element, after = I tried with data and with template data in the 1st page
    //protocol_file = $("input[name='json_path']")
    //filename = $("input[name='img_path']")
    
    //Second try to send data in new url => undefined
    $('#protocol_file').html(data.protocol_file);
    $('#filename').html(data.filename);
    
    //Third try => GetElementById is undefined error 
    //document.GetElementById("protocol_file").innerHTML = $("input[name='json_path']")
    //document.GetElementById("filename").innerHTML = $("input[name='img_path']")
    
    //Fourth try => synthaxe error, I also tried with a + like in some forum but it consider like a str and concat all...
    window.location.href="/filmchromique/result/" {data:data}
    
    #this one is working but with no data sended .... 
    //window.location.href="/filmchromique/result/"
},
error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

});

The view of the result page :

```
class displayResultPage(TemplateView):
template_name = 'result.html'
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(displayResultPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return kwargs

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    bar = self.request.POST.get('foo', None)
    if bar: self.template_name = 'result.html'

    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

In my template result, I have nothing particular, only maybe these part could be interesting :

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 30%" class="row gx-5 justify-content-center">
{% if protocol_file is not null %}
    <p id="protocol_file">Your file is here : {{ filename }}</p>
{% else %}
    <h1 style="color: indianred">You must launch an analysis before accessing an image on this page</h1>
{% endif %}
```

```
{% if protocol_file is not null %}
<div class="row gx-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-6">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="{% url 'json:downloadFile' protocol_file %}">Save protocol to local</a>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-6">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="{% url 'json:downloadFile' filename %}">Save image to local</a>
    </div>
<br>
</div>
```

I do not find a way to send the context. If you have any idea how I can do it please

Have a good day

EDIT

The problem seems not to be in the Ajax side but in the result view, here named displayResultPage. I used the debugger, and in the second post def, data are in the request (POST). So I had the idea to add them in the current context :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["filename"] = self.request.POST.get("img_path")
    context["protocol_file"] = self.request.POST.get("json_path")...
```

But the data are not displayed in the template.

When I use the debbugger, following the workflow :

> the post function is called -> self.get_context_data called in the
> post function -> return self.render_to_response of the post function
> -> something done in class TemplateView -> come back in the get_context_data of displayResultPage -> something done in class
> TemplatView -> page displayed

in the "come back in the get_context_data of displayResultPage" step, I do not find my data given to the context in the "the post function is called" step.

If you have any idea why, I think it is the solution here :) If I find a way I will post it.

Thanks

Comment: You've to specify url inside your ajax `url:""`

Comment: Thanks. In the beginning, I specified it (url: "resultURL"), but I need time to process the data, and if I do it, the page is imediatly changed without data inside

Comment: Hello @Angioedema02 can you explain more about current problem?

Comment: My problem is to send data also naiming context to the result page. Right now, the redirections is okay to the result page but I do not find a way to sen context data using ajax

Comment: So you wanted to check your context data in browser console before redirecting to another page ?

Comment: I have data as a filename in the context in launchCtd view. I want to send this informations to the result view to fill filename in the template
The filename in the ajax success function is present, I can catch information of the launchCtd view. If I do a console.log(data.filename) here I have what I want. 
But the result page is load and the filename in the template result is not fill...

Comment: I have two hypothesis : 
- the context data are not send, and so how I can do it in the success ajax (to send to the result view and so to the template) ?
- the result view do not catch the context data sended. However, if I send data without ajax, with pure django, the code is okay. But I need js and ajax for more avanced functionalities in the page.

Comment: The problem is not the ajax. After some test with the debeug, the data is received in the class displayResult in the second post def. But I still have a problem. I will edit the post with more details